# nginx: "proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" does not work properly

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have many virtual hosts on a server and I created this "default test site" to test some stuff.

all works fine but the "proxy_set_header".
It actually proxies the requests but show the proxied host name instead of the requested host name.

Do you have any idea on that ?

```
server {
    # SRV NAME
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name default.it;
    large_client_header_buffers  4 16k;


    # TLS
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/websites/wildcard.it/wildcard.it.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/websites/wildcard.it/wildcard.it.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/default.it.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/default.it.error.log;
location / {
    proxy_pass                          https://default-portals.it/; 
    proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    proxy_ssl_verify                    off;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate       /etc/ssl/websites/default.it/default.it.ca-bundle;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth              2;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse             on;
    proxy_ssl_name                      $proxy_host;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use $host Instead of $http_host: try changing the directive to proxy_set_header Host $host;. The $host variable in nginx contains the server name from the request line or the host name from the request's Host header field, without the port if it's present.

Comment: There seems to be some garbage after the `proxy_pass` statement and before the `proxy_set_header Host` statement. A missing `;` will cause the next statement to be ignored.